# How would I create a simple checkout cart that puts in items as I click a button?

Tags: html, css, web-applications

I am working on my first web app and it is a restaurant management system. I am trying to create a simple checkout cart that populates order items as the buttons that represent each item are clicked. Here is my code for the buttons themselves but I have no idea how to make a shopping cart to store the items on screen. Thank you very much.

```
  <!--menu items-->
 <ul id="keyboard"> 
  <div class="card-body row no-gutters align-items-center fixed-center">

    <li class="letter" value="Beef Stew">Beef Stew</li>  
    <li class="letter">Cheese Grits</li>  
    <li class="letter">Beef Stroganoff</li>  
    <li class="letter clearl">Pork Chops</li>  
    <li class="letter">Onion Soup</li>  
    <li class="letter">Mac N' Cheese</li> 

    <li class="letter clearl">Spinach Lasagna</li>  
    <li class="letter ">Chicken Pot Pie</li>
</ul>  

<ul id="keyboard"> 
   <div class="card-body row no-gutters align-items-center fixed-center">       
     <li class="delete lastitem">Clear Order</li>  
     <li class="delete lastitem">Delete</li>
     <li class="submit">Checkout</li> 
 <br>
 <br>
 </div>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have any cart functionality yet? This will need to use some form of server-side coding if it is going to be secure. In the meantime you should look into tutorials on HTML forms and form processing.

Comment: There is no functionality yet. I'll definitely listen to your advice and check out some form tutorials. Thank you!